# what is the right way to sign in google: GoogleAuthUtil or GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, oauth, google-oauth

What is the right way to sign in with google: GoogleAuthUtil or GoogleApiClient. So I want to login my app with Oauth supported, but I see two approaches which have same result:

- [GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html)
- [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)

And what is the different between using GoogleAuthUtil and GoogleApiClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google APIs Client Library is a cross platform library for interacting with Google's services and the Android version is implemented by using GoogleAuthUtil.

Comment: So GoogleAuthUtil is enough for authentication ?

Comment: If you are developing for some other platform than Android you can not use GoogleAuthUtil as it is an Android specific library.
If you are developing a cross platform application you can use the Google APIs Client Library in your shared code for for both Android and other platforms.                                                           you should use GoogleAuthUtil Clien is suffiecient..

Answer (score 2):

GoogleAuthUtil provides low-level functionality.  This is useful if you want to actually get OAuth2 tokens or refresh codes, or deliberately show a dialog to choose account.  Most people use this to get a refresh token to send to their server, but you need some permissions for this (GET_ACCOUNTS I think?).

GoogleApiClient wraps this up a bit and handles the OAuth2 work for you, provided you're using the APIs that are provided.  So if you're using com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive stuff, you'll have to use GoogleApiClient.

If you want to use both (you want to do stuff locally *and* send a refresh token to your server), use GoogleAuthUtil first and provide the account name in GoogleApiClient's builder.  If your accounts, scopes, and applications all match, GoogleAuthUtil will provide any prompts that are necessary, and GoogleApiClient should just connect silently.

Comment: Could you please point me to on how I can use `GoogleAuthUtil` to obtain `refresh_token`?!

Comment: The short answer is you don't.  If you want it on the device, don't bother; GoogleAuthUtil manages it for you. If you want to use it on your server, you can get an authorization code that your backend can exchange for a refresh token.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth#androidIdTokens

See the section on providing authorization to your backend.

Comment: If you want to access authenticated stuff on a device, ask GoogleAuthUtil for an access token right before each batch of stuff.  If the token is expired, GoogleAuthUtil will get a new one for you. Either way you get what should be a good token. Use it. If your request fails, tell GoogleAuthUtil to expire that token and ask for a new one.

Comment: Does `GoogleAuthUtil` show a dialogue (to choose account) every time token is expired?

Comment: No, it only shows a dialog when the user has de-authed your app.