# Access Google Drive API using GoogleAuthUtil token

Tags: android, google-play-services

TL/DR: How to access google services from a service running in the background?

There are 2 versions of connecting to Drive API

- [java](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) which tells how to use `Credential` object
- [android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api) which tells you how to use `GoogleApiClient`

None of them telling how to use it in the background service, e.g. saving user data every now and then.

Also in another [android guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth) I found use of `GoogleAuthUtil` which can help me to obtain token which I can use later on but I can not find a single example on how to use Drive API through token!

Answer (score 0):

About sample code of save file to Google Drive, you can refer this link(https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/EditContentsActivity.java).But, this sample is using AsyncTask instead of Service as a background process.
If really like to implement that process in Service, you can do it by copy-paste EditContentsAsyncTask's code to Service.
Reason not to use service in the sample code is because Service still runs in your application's main thread by default,
About Service and AsyncTask, you can refer this link "Should you use a service or a thread?"(http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

And the different between using GoogleAuthUtil and GoogleApiClient,you can refer this link([what is the right way to sign in google: GoogleAuthUtil or GoogleApiClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524317/what-is-the-right-way-to-sign-in-google-googleauthutil-or-googleapiclient)).

Comment: Basically I'm asking for an advice or a piece of code on how to have access to a user's drive after some time, e.g. using access/refresh tokens and stuff